# Java for-loop iteration

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator

Consider the following piece of code:

```
final String str = "1-2-3";

for (int idx = 0; idx < str.split("\\D").length; idx++) {
    // do something
}
```

How many times will this portion of code: `str.split("\\D")` be executed? Three times? Or will the compiler see that as `str` is declared as `final`, only one call to `str.split("\\D")` will be enough?

Comment: what is the problem u r facing in it ??Post u r problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be interesting to you. For this code:

```
class Foo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final String str = "1-2-3";

    for (int idx = 0; idx < str.split("\\D").length; idx++) {
    }
  }
}
```

the bytecode is:

```
Compiled from "Foo.java"
class Foo {
  Foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_2      
       2: iload_2       
       3: ldc           #2                  // String 1-2-3
       5: ldc           #3                  // String \D
       7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.split:(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
      10: arraylength   
      11: if_icmpge     20
      14: iinc          2, 1
      17: goto          2
      20: return        
}
```

It is clear that `split` is executed <strike>three</strike> FOUR times, regardless of the finality of `str`, and of invariance of `split`.

Comment: Good answer (especially the bytecode), the only problem is that it's executed _four_ times since it does so for the final "false" condition as well. Change that and it'll be perfect :-)

Comment: That's better, +1 :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Way ahead of you :) It said "four" for like 20 minutes :D

Answer (score 3):

JLS 14.14.1.2 states (`Expression` here being the middle bit of the `for` statement):

> Next, a for iteration step is performed, as follows. If the Expression is present, **it is evaluated.**

That means it does it on *each* iteration step, there is no leeway there in the specification for optimisation.

You can see something similar with the following code:

```
class Test {
    public static int getSeven () {
        System.out.println ("called getSeven()");
        return 7;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        for (int i = 1; i <= getSeven(); i++) {
            System.out.println ("i = " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

When you run that, you get:

```
called getSeven()
i = 1
called getSeven()
i = 2
called getSeven()
i = 3
called getSeven()
i = 4
called getSeven()
i = 5
called getSeven()
i = 6
called getSeven()
i = 7
called getSeven()
```

showing that the function is called *each* time through the loop (including the exit condition).

That means your particular case won't call it once *or* three times, it will actually call it *four* times, with `idx` set respectively to `0`, `1`, `2` and the final check at `3`.

Comment: 200% agree but wont it get execute to check for failure condition?.

Comment: @captain: Yes. It "gets seven" eight times.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The split method will be executed 3 times to determine the length, **BUT** this has nothing to do with the fact that the string is final or not. It would be execute the same even if the strign was not final.

See this [example](http://ideone.com/kIo0LH):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String g = "bla bla";
        for (int i = 0; i < index(g); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Round");
        }
    }

    public static int index(String input)
    {
        System.out.println("index Called");
        return input.length();
    }
}
```

The output will show for each round: *index Called*

Comment: Thanks. What will happen if I don't declare the string as `final`?

Comment: The execution will not be different depending on the string if it is final or not.

Comment: JLS 14.14.1.2 states that the expression is evaluated for each iteration. That doesn't seem to gel with what you're saying here.

Comment: @CloudyMarble: How is the source code of `split` relevant to knowing how many times it is being called (from outside itself)?

Comment: @paxdiablo the JLS 14.14.1.2 refer to the for statetment, the question refers to how many times the statement str.split("\\D") is beeing executed.

Comment: The split is called 3 times, i edited my answer, had to test it in the mean while, but the issue with final or not has nothing to do with the execution of the for loop at this place.

Comment: Cloudy, it's the `for` controlling how many times split is called so 14.14.1.2 is the correct place to look. Source code for split is irrelevant. Though I see now you've fixed the answer, so that's moot. BTW, it's called four times rather than three since it has to do the final failing check as well.

Answer (score 1):

How does `for loop` works

1. Initialization ---> `int idx = 0`
2. Condition check ---> `str.split("\\D").length;`
3. Execute Loop body
4. Increment index `idx++`
5. check condition  `str.split("\\D").length;`
6. Execute Loop body
7. Repeat steps 4-6 till `idx < str.split("\\D").length()` fails

So every time your `idx < str.split("\\D").length()` will get executed.
I would say it will get execute three times for condition match and one last for condition fail.

Answer (score 1):

There's a 100% sure way to see if a compiler optimizes something - look at the compilation result. I've included the byte code in the response and I think it's pretty obvious - the split method will be executed multiple times in the first case regardless of the final keyword (the invoke virtual line is the split method call, you can understand what is looped by the goto statement).

Different compilers MAY behave in a different way, though.
Feel free to retest this on your desired environment (you can view bytecode with 'javap -c classname'

```
public class gti {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        final String str = "1-2-3";

        for (int idx = 0; idx < str.split("\\D").length; idx++) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

results in:

```
public class gti {
  public gti();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_2
       2: iload_2
       3: ldc           #2                  // String 1-2-3
       5: ldc           #3                  // String \D
       7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.split:(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
      10: arraylength
      11: if_icmpge     20
      14: iinc          2, 1
      17: goto          2
      20: return
}
```

while

```
public class gti {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        final String str = "1-2-3";
        int length = str.split("\\D").length;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < length; idx++) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

results in:

```
public class gti {
  public gti();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String 1-2-3
       2: ldc           #3                  // String \D
       4: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.split:(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
       7: arraylength
       8: istore_2
       9: iconst_0
      10: istore_3
      11: iload_3
      12: iload_2
      13: if_icmpge     22
      16: iinc          3, 1
      19: goto          11
      22: return
}
```

Comment: You're right about the 100% sure way but I have to disagree with you that some compilers may do something different. The JLS requires the expression to be evaluated, any compiler that doesn't do so is not a Java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

str.split("\D") will not split your str string it returns new instance of String[] array.
Answer is 3 times str.split("\D") will be executed.